# List ports of all running node apps called "app.js" on linux (One-liner)

Tags: linux

I am trying to put together a One-liner Linux command which will allow me to list the ports of all running node apps which have the name" app.js".

I am not sure how to pipe a piped output to another command which will also need to be piped.  I can do this with three commands, but would like to know if it is possible to do it in one, without using a temporary file.

```sh
ps -a|grep node|awk '{print $1}'|xargs ps -Flww -p|grep "node app.js"|awk '{print $4}'>findNodeAppJsPorts.txt
netstat -tulpn|grep -f findNodeAppJsPorts.txt
rm findNodeAppJsPorts.txt
```

I'm sure that some Linux Ninjas know how to do this, 
can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use bash, you can try out [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) to get rid of temporary file. For example:

```sh
netstat -tulpn | grep -f <(pgrep -a node | grep 'node app.js' | awk '{print $1}')
```

Comment: I did not know that I could use parentheses to specify a block and then direct that block to grep.  Thanks Oleg Andriyanov.

Comment: Thank you for the help Oleg.  I ended up changing the command somewhat, but using your substitution suggestion I found a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion Oleg, using your suggestion I was able to get what I wanted with this command:

```bash
(ps -aux|grep "node"|grep ".js"|grep -v "/forever/"|awk '{print $2}') | while read line; do lsof -Pan -p $line -i -w; done
```

which does the following:

- Finds all process ids (PID) of runnin node servers
- excludes the forever monitor
- and feads each PID to the lsof command just after the -p option
- and finally prints all open ports these node servers use.